# How to use the same instance of a SET across different requests in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am trying to achieve a functionality to queue up a list of IDs or users that have connected to my application and dump it into the database every minute.

In order to achieve this I intend to store the IDs of said users in a set and then store the set in the database and empty the set every minute.

My challenge however includes

- how to use the same instance of the set across various requests from various users so that I can have a list of the various users.

I can't make use of sessions because As I mentioned above, the set is going to be IDs of different users using in different sessions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a class level variable in a `@Service`, as it's default scope is singleton or a static variable. But you must maintain the content of the `Set` properly, because it can lead to memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Simplistically, you could use a thread safe set implementation for your problem, but I personally would try to use a "Publish-Subscribe" pattern where the publisher publishes an event (in your case, the id) and the subscriber can (synchronously or asynchronously) reduce the events to a set and flush them to the database.